# Calibrate camera using cube

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

Is it possible to calibrate the camera using a cube with a length of 1cm on each side? It is obvious that we need to find 6 point correspondence taking into consideration that the shouldn't be on same plane and on same line. The first part can be easily handled but my problem is that how we can ensure that none of the points or on the same line?

Answer (score 0):

Rather vague question. My answers:

1. Yes, it is possible to calibrate a pinhole model by matching the 3D location of the visible vertices of a cube in general position to their projections in one image. Four points on one face define a homography which can be decomposed using Zhang's method to recover the focal length. The extra visible points can be used to tighten the estimate.
2. Whether 1cm side length is adequate depends entirely on the actual lens used and the cube's distance from it. Accuracy will degrade the as the portion of the image covered by the cube is reduced.
3. Calibrating the nonlinear lens distortion will be almost impossible. The only information the cube provides is the orthogonality and length of the sides, i.e. few data points. Unless you take lots of images you won't have enough effective constraints.
4. Your cube had better be machined very accurately, if you hope for any precision.
5. A dodecahedron makes for a much better rig, if you really want to use a 3D one.